# Created a friend in class, gives 'no input files' error

Tags: c++, dev-c++, cppunit

I am an absolute beginner in C++ and trying to learn how to create a friend inside a class. I did everything exactly as the teacher did, but the compiler gives me two errors:

```
[Error] hj²k.cpp: No such file or directory
[Error] no input files
```

Where did I make a mistake? Could you please explain like I'm five?

```
class guts {
    public:
        guts() {gutsVar = 0};
    private:
        int gutsVar;
    friend void gutsfriend (guts &gutsObj);
    };

void gutsfriend (guts &gutsObj) {
        gutsObj.gutsVar = 99;
        cout << gutsObj.gutsVar << endl;
    }
int main () {
    guts obj2;
    gutsfriend (obj2);
}
```

I expect the output to be 99, but it doesn't even give me the blackboard. It says compilation terminated.

Comment: If the compiler is complaining about that, then you are probably not compiling properly/indicating files properly. Could you post how you try to compile your code?

Comment: Besides the other problems the line `guts() {gutsVar = 0};` should be `guts() {gutsVar = 0;}`. The semicolon has to be after the statement in the function body. There does not need to be a semicolon after a function definition inside of class.

Comment: The problem is not in the program, but in the way you invoke the compiler.

Comment: Looks like you not compiling the file at all. Stop looking at the program and investigate how you're invoking the compiler.

Comment: See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125927/compiling-c-code-raising-no-input-files-fatal-error) for more on your issue. Remember to try googling first before creating questions on here!

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Your code is ok after you fix the problem with the semicolon mentioned by @DevonCornwall https://wandbox.org/permlink/jDdllYggr08jDJrA

Comment: It's not his code, his compiler can't find the source .cpp file.

Comment: I fixed the problem @DevonCornwall mentioned, I try to compile (execute/compile on devc++) and it gives me the same error. ı wrote the code myself, did not copy paste or anything. It also automatically opens a file called Makefile.win, which has all sorts of stuff I don't understand. What do I do? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I just started learning this thing two days ago.

Comment: Can you show us the command you use to build your program? What are you typing in your console?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it was because I was working on an old project. I closed the project, closed the compiler and opened it again, started a new source file. I copy-pasted the whole thing and it worked. Thanks everyone! Sorry for being silly.